# java.lang.NullPointerException in Java Swing code

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

Can anyone tell me why the following code is throwing a null pointer exception? The exception is thrown at the line
numberJTextField.addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter(numberJTextField));
in the class InputJFrame1.java.

```
import java.awt.*;

public class InputJFrame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    private javax.swing.JTextField numberJTextField;

    public InputJFrame1()
    {     
         numberJTextField.addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter(numberJTextField));
    }

    private void initComponents() 
    {
        numberJTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        getContentPane().add(numberJTextField);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InputJFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InputJFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InputJFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InputJFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                            new InputJFrame1().setVisible(true);
                                        }
                                    });
    }
}



import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter
{
    private JTextField jTextField;

    MyMouseAdapter(JTextField jTextField)
    {
        this.jTextField=jTextField;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
          jTextField.setForeground(Color.red);
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at javaapplication8.InputJFrame1.(InputJFrame1.java:9)    at
>   javaapplication8.InputJFrame1$1.run(InputJFrame1.java:73)     at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Comment: Please attach stacktrace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't remove the `initComponents` from the constructor. It makes sure that all components are properly initialized before using them, so it should be the first line of your constructor.

```
public InputJFrame1()
{     
     initComponents();
     numberJTextField.addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter(numberJTextField));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're forget to initialize `numberJTextField` (and Other Components) on default constructor

```
public InputJFrame1()
    {     
         initComponents();
         numberJTextField.addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter(numberJTextField));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

The field `numberJTextField` has not been assigned at the time the constructor is called.  Try calling the `initComponents` method in the constructor, prior to adding the MouseListener.

```
public class InputJFrame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    private javax.swing.JTextField numberJTextField;

    public InputJFrame1()
    {     
         initComponents(); //Init components before using textfield
         numberJTextField.addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter(numberJTextField));
    }

    private void initComponents() 
    {
        numberJTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        getContentPane().add(numberJTextField);
    }
```

Comment: Or why set the listener in the constructor at all? Move the listener to `initComponents()` - where it belongs with the rest.

Answer (score 1):

```
public InputJFrame1() {
        numberJTextField.addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter(numberJTextField));
    }
```

`numberJTextField` is null thats why.

Comment: Yes I had forgotten to initialize the components. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're instantiating a new `InputJFrame1`, but *not calling* your initialisation method, meaning `numberJTextField` is null.

I would put your initialisation code within your constructor. You can then mark the appropriate fields as `final`, and the compiler will tell you if you forget to initialise them.

```
private final javax.swing.JTextField numberJTextField;
```

Using `final` is a great way to avoid such initialisation problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Will follow it. :)